# How to Debug class procedure in Python?

Tags: python, django-class-based-views

I am working on class-based views on Django. I need to debug the functions line by line in a Class. I have added the breakpoints on various rows but when i debug VS-code reads the class at the startup but later does not stop at breakpoints when i click on controls that i want to debug.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: are you using the `Python: Django` debug profile?

Comment: Correct. It works ok if i have function based view but not working for class base...

Comment: I figured that out... I had added breakpoints at def level while breakpoints should be at line of code. Sorry for inconvenience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting so i can close the question.

I figured that out... I had added breakpoints at def/function line while breakpoints should be at line of code. Sorry for inconvenience...

But this may help other who may stuck on the same...